# setting default options for form elements in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to change the default behavior of form elements in CakePHP without altering the cake directory? In my case I would like to disable validation error output on inputs but would prefer to not have to set the option for every single one on a site. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1639/x7-3-1-5-options-inputDefaults

> You can declare a set of default
>   options for `input()` with the
>   `inputDefaults` key to customize your
>   default input creation.
>
> ```
> echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
>     'inputDefaults' => array(
>         'label' => false,
>         'div' => false
>     )
> ));
> ```